# How to fold Esther's scroll

Tags: megillat-esther, how-to

The custom is to unroll the *m'gila* and fold it over, 'page' over 'page', before reading it in public on *Purim*, then to roll it up again before reciting the *b'racha* after the reading. Suppose there's no one at hand to help you hold it in place on a lectern or table while you read it. You will want to fold it in such a way that

- the 'page breaks' are between columns of text,
- the *m'gila* will not roll up

  - even while you're 'turning the page',
- it's easy to 'turn the page', and,
- preferably, it's fast and easy to roll it up as soon as you've finished reading.

I haven't found such a folding method, and I struggle with my *m'gila* every time I read it.

Can you recommend a folding method, preferably (though not necessarily) one that

- has worked in practice, and
- works even if the *m'gila* is being held (there's no lectern or table)?

Bear in mind that (at least in my *m'gila*) not all columns are the same width, so not all 'pages' will be the same width if the 'page breaks' are between columns.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VryBSWQCPvk (I've never tried this)

Answer (score 9):

I can tell you what I do with my own Megillah, although it's relatively small - 11" tall and 48" wide - so YMMV if you have a large one.

It has ten columns (all the same width except for the last, which is a little narrower). I fold it 3-4-3 (there's no requirement that each fold be the same width), and crease the folds a little so that it naturally bends in those places in the future. Sometimes I fold it in an S shape (the second and third pages facing each other), other times as a G (the third page inside the first two). With the first way, I can tuck the fold between the first and second pages into the curl at the end of the Megillah, and then I don't need to hold both ends; on the other hand, the second way makes it easier to transition from the first page to the second. (By the time I reach the third page, though, I almost always have it in a Z shape, and can tuck the fold to the right of that page into the opening curl.) Either way, though, it's easy enough to handle whether I'm reading at a lectern or not, although again that might just be because it's smaller than the typical one.

Comment: How many rows per column does it have?

Comment: @DoubleAA: [42](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Answer_to_Life.png).

Comment: 42 lines on 11" tall?! That's really small. Is that 11" of klaf or ksav?

Comment: @DoubleAA: 11" of klaf. The ksav takes up 7.5", so about six lines per inch. I guess I never realized that it is relatively small, then; it feels comfortable enough when I'm reading it.

Answer (score 3):

You could fold the megilla in half and secure the beginning of the scroll to the end of the scroll using 2 or 3 binder clips. This creates a two-sided scroll with half of the columns on each side. This setup will require only 1 page turn during the entire reading.

Because the attached beginning and the end pull in opposite directions, the megilla should stay pretty flat without rolling up, assuming you have a good crease by the fold in the middle.

This setup is very helpful when the reader has no table and no-one to help hold the megilla. The reader can hold each side of the 2-sided scroll in each hand and continuously adjust the sag for the most comfortable reading position for each column.

Comment: This would only work for a relatively narrow Megillah (probably at least 42 lines per column). Some Megillot are up to 38 columns long!

Comment: Yes - I've tested this with a 42 line megilla that has only 10 columns.